# Unable to create one to one relationship with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-workbench

I am using MariaDB server and MySQL workbench for client and SQLAlchemy with python. I have two tables `users` and `sessions`. What I want to achieve is a one-to-one mapping between these two columns, that is each user can have one and only one session. Here is my model declaration.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column('id', INTEGER, Sequence('users_id_seq', start=1,
                                        increment=1),
                primary_key=True)

    email = Column('email', VARCHAR(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    first_name = Column('first_name', CHAR(50))
    last_name = Column('last_name', CHAR(50))
    password = Column('password', VARCHAR(128))
    profile_pic = Column('profile_pic', VARCHAR(500))

    # relationships with other tables
    session = relationship('Session', uselist=False, back_populates='user')
```

and

```
class Session(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sessions'

    user_id = Column('user_id', INTEGER, ForeignKey('users.id'),
                     nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    token = Column('token', VARCHAR(36), nullable=False)

    # relationship
    user = relationship('User', back_populates='session')
```

That seem to execute fine but when I reverse engineer the schema using MySQL workbench it generates a one to many relationship between the two table. Here's the image:

[image]

Comment: I think there is a problem with your back_populates tag. Try change back_populates='session' to back_populates='sessions' and back_populates='user' to back_populates='users'

Comment: @KevinMartins The `back_populates` arg should specify the name of the reciprocal relationship attribute to allow bi-directional behavior, and appear correct in this case.

Comment: I don’t have a lot of experience with the workbench GUI but shouldn’t there also be the little key next to `sessions.user_id` to signify it is the primary key of the table? If it has to be unique on `user_id` then that enforces your one-to-one. I see that your sqlalchemy model has `sessions.user_id` defined with `primary_key = True`, but the schema diagram looks different.

Comment: @SuperShoot You're right, I made the wrong observation.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one

Comment: @SuperShoot you're right, there seems to be some issue with the tool. When I try to insert a record with the duplicate `user_id`, it doesn't allow me to do so. The relationship seems to be present but the tool is somehow not able to reverse engineer it, I guess.

Comment: @SuperShoot even after mentioning `unique=True`  on `sessions.user_id`, it doesn't show it in the diagram.

Comment: Are you dropping the tables and creating them again after you make each change, or using a migration tool?

Comment: @SuperShoot right now since I've almost no data, I am actually dropping the tables and creating the collections again.